# Stitching two analytic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on the open unit disc and let $g$ be an analytic function on the complement of its closure.
Further assume that the two functions have a the same continuous limit on the common boundary of their domain.

Is it possible to build an entire function that settles with $f$ and $g$.

The question is a it vague I'm afraid...

Comment: No way. For example, let $f = 0$ and let $g = x^2 + y^2 - 1$.

Comment: Your g is not analytic. No?

Comment: By analytic do you mean complex-analytic (in one complex variable)? My $g$ is a polynomial, so it's certainly real-analytic in two variables. :-)

Comment: Oh, oops, I overlooked that you said "entire". My apologies; ignore my comments.

Comment: Reflection Principle (and perhaps Riemann Mapping theorem).

Comment: The only problematic points are the ones on the unit circle. Use Morera's theorem to see that the glued function is indeed holomorphic.

Comment: @paulgarrett For the reflection principle, you need to know something about the boundary values (they must lie in an analytic arc locally). Getting that is deep, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer, indeed, one must have an involutive anti-holomorphic map that fixes the "boundary" curve, as many of us know. So, yes, there must be an anti-analytic map (akin to complex conjugation for the real line, or $1/\overline{z}$ for the unit circle) that fixes pointwise the desired boundary arc. The Riemann mapping theorem does non-constructively make a simply-connected, bounded region into the disk... so we have an example-existence result. But in any case the Morera's theorem argument that proves the usual reflection principle can apply.

Comment: @paulgarrett Here $f$ is not assumed injective. I don't see what you'd use the Riemann mapping theorem for. And not all boundary values of functions continuous on the closed disk and holomorphic on the open disk allow reflection, so you need to work to get that under the given circumstances, you can reflect.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm not attempting to assert anything too substantive: only, first, that the same Morera-thm argument as in reflection principle's _proof_ applies to the form of the question I saw here; second, that one might wonder (though this was not asked) to what extent all such questions reduce to a single one... thinking of Riemann Mapping. The examples of mapping polygons to disks illustrates (to me) that such questions do not reduce to a single case. Just free-associating, perhaps...

Answer (score 4):

By the assumption

> Further assume that the two functions have a the same continuous limit on the common boundary of their domain

the function

$$h(z) = \begin{cases} f(z) &, \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1 \\ g(z) &, \lvert z\rvert \geqslant 1\end{cases}$$

is well-defined, and continuous on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \partial \mathbb{D}$.

For a point $z_0 \in \partial\mathbb{D}$, consider the disk $U := D_{1/2}(z_0)$ and use Morera's theorem to find that $h$ is holomorphic on $U$: Let $\Delta \subset U$ be a closed triangle, and $A = \Delta \cap \overline{\mathbb{D}}$, $B = \Delta \setminus \mathbb{D}$. Then

$$\int_{\partial\Delta} h(z)\,dz = \int_{\partial A} h(z)\,dz + \int_{\partial B} h(z)\,dz$$

since the integrals over $\Delta\cap \partial\mathbb{D}$ cancel due to the opposite orientation this arc has in $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ [or $\Delta \cap \partial\mathbb{D}$ consists of one or two isolated points or is empty, in which cases that part of the integrals is $0$ trivially]. For $\varepsilon > 0$ let $A_\varepsilon = \Delta \cap \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1-\varepsilon\}$ and $B_\varepsilon = \Delta \cap \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \geqslant 1+\varepsilon\}$. By Cauchy's integral theorem, we have

$$\int_{\partial A_\varepsilon} h(z)\,dz = 0 = \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon} h(z)\,dz.$$

By the uniform continuity of $h$ in $U$, we have

$$\int_{\partial A} h(z)\,dz = \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \int_{\partial A_\varepsilon} h(z)\,dz = 0$$

and

$$\int_{\partial B} h(z)\,dz = \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon} h(z)\,dz = 0,$$

whence Morera's theorem tells us that $h$ is holomorphic on $U$.

Hence $h$ is entire.

Comment: What is $U$, not clear..

Comment: To use Morera's theorem, you have to check that an integral vanishes ... why does that integral vanish here?

Comment: @TalPorat I decided to name the disk $D_{1/2}(z_0)$, but forgot to replace all occurrences of $U$ that I had in mind.

Comment: @GregMartin Take a triangle in the small disk. If it doesn't intersect the unit circle, Cauchy's integral theorem says the integral is $0$. If it does, take two circular arcs at radii $1-\varepsilon$ and $1+\varepsilon$ to split the triangle into a curvilinear triangle and a curvilinear quadrilateral, one entirely in the unit disk, one entirely outside, plus two very short line segments crossing the unit circle. Apply Cauchy's integral theorem to the two curvilinear polygons. Then let $\varepsilon \to 0$. Use that $h$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: That sounds right to me (and also sounds familiar from the proof of the Schwarz reflection principle). I think you should include those details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Joining $f$ and $g_1$ would give you an entire function, which by the identity principle would have to agree with any other joining of $f$ with $g_2$ say, implying $g_1=g_2$. Thus if it is possible for $f$, it can only be done with one specific $g$.

This implies that it can be done if and only if $f$ is the restriction of some entire function to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, and $g$ is $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{D}$.

EDIT: I forgot to take into account behaviour on the boundary $\partial\mathbb{D}$. However as in Daniel's answer this follows from Morea's theorem and continuity at the boundary of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score -1):

Since both functions are continuous along the boundary (in particular, having no poles), they can be analytically continued. For example, let $p$ be a point on the unit circle, and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $p$ small enough so that both $f(z), g(z)$ can be analytically continued.

Then $f(z) - g(z) = 0$ along the arc of the unit circle contained in $U$, so $f(z) - g(z) = 0$ everywhere on $U$. In particular, the analytic continuation of $g(z)$ into $U$ just agrees with $f(z)$. This holds for arbitrary $p$.

So, yes -- the "join" of the two functions will be entire.

EDIT: This answer is not correct (see comments).

Comment: It isn't true that being continuous on the boundary means that it can be analytically continued: consider $f(z) = \sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: Hm, right; I'm being careless. I'll hold off on further attempts to answer this question for now...