# A Continuous Extension of the Derivative of a Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Greeings,

I'm playing around with this idea and, frankly, I'm stuck. Perhaps, someone will know of an answer offhand? Here's the idea.
Define
$$
    \Omega
\::=\:
    \{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}
\,\cup\,
    \{z\in\mathbb{C} : 1 < |z| \leq 2\}.
$$
Suppose that $f : \text{cl}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Under what circumstances is $f'$ uniformly bounded on $\Omega$?
> 2. Were it the case that $f'$ is uniformly bounded on $\Omega$, we would then have that $f'$ extends to a uniformly continuous function on $\text{cl}(\Omega)$ (this I've already proved!). However, does the existence of this extension imply that $f$ is differentiable on the unit circle? (if so, then its derivative must there be equal to the extension of $f'$.)

For context, here is an (outline of an) answer to the problem in the analogous situation for real functions.

> **Solution to an analogous but different problem:** If $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, is differentiable on $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$, and the derivative function $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$, then $f'$ extends to a uniformly continuous function on $[0,2]$. In this case, one can use the mean value theorem to show that $f$ is differentiable at the point $1$. Indeed, where $(x_n)$ is any sequence in $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$ converging to $1$, the MVT lets us construct $(y_n)$ with $0<|y_n-1|\leq|x_n-1|$ and $f(x_n)-f(1) = f'(y_n)(x_n-1)$. Then, letting $n\to\infty$ shows that the finite differences converge to the value of $f'$'s extension at $1$. Hmmmmm, can the argument be modified to work in the complex case, where we lack an MVT but gain analyticity?

I've been thinking about this for a while now (this isn't for a graded assignment, or anything like that) but I can't make any progress. If anyone has some insight into the answer to these questions, I'd certainly be grateful!

edits: self-conscious rephrasing of non-mathematical content.

Comment: In fact, [$f$ is holomorphic on $\{z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001798/stitching-two-analytic-functions).

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm going to need to take a few minutes to read through that. Thank you for the reference, by the way (sorry, I had not seen that question!)